# how to add image on end of <textarea> in user selected text row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**My Need is**

In my page have one textarea html tag.. The user can able to type a document in that textarea.

At the same time user have any doubt on single sentences of the document. in that time user can able to select the doubt text.

If user select the sentences for clarification , end of the sentences a image can added like red mark or tag

**I have value**

I have done the selected row number and selected text value using jQuery

**My Question is**

How to add the image on end of textarea.. and i have a problem on line based image display

for example if i have clarification on third line i select the the text and end of the text[border of the textarea] a image can marked

Please help me..

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Don't you have any code to pose here?

Comment: i have a code for only fine the row of cursor position or row number and user selected text values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
You first need to create an `<img>` element, then calculate its future position based off of several variables including the `scrollTop` of the `<textarea>`. Then, you'll need to use CSS positioning in conjunction with some nifty Javascript to place the `<img>` at the correct location. I've created a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewgu/rxmzefje/) to show you the basics of how this should be done. If you want to allow text wrapping, you might want to use a library such as [this one](https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position).

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: You can simplify this code a bit with jQuery, but I decided to stick to vanilla JS here just to keep things simple. That way, it's also more compatible and will work before jQuery loads, or if jQuery fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JQuery insertafter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) to insert an element to your HTML .

```
$( "<img src='' >" ).insertAfter( "#myElement" );
```

you can use this function to select the text per line number

```
function selectTextareaLine(tarea,lineNum) {
    lineNum--; // array starts at 0
    var lines = tarea.value.split("\n");

    // calculate start/end
    var startPos = 0, endPos = tarea.value.length;
    for(var x = 0; x < lines.length; x++) {
        if(x == lineNum) {
            break;
        }
        startPos += (lines[x].length+1);

    }

    var endPos = lines[lineNum].length+startPos;

    // do selection
    // Chrome / Firefox

    if(typeof(tarea.selectionStart) != "undefined") {
        tarea.focus();
        tarea.selectionStart = startPos;
        tarea.selectionEnd = endPos;
        return true;
    }

    // IE
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        tarea.focus();
        tarea.select();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd("character", endPos);
        range.moveStart("character", startPos);
        range.select();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

`var textArea = document.getElementById('Textarea');` `selectTextareaLine(textArea,3); // selects line 2`

I got this code from this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5enfp/

Comment: Thanx Rami.. But i have 10 line in textarea if user select second row text. i image must shown in end of second line[border of second line]