# How to get the line number from Iframe using jquery in html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In my page have one `textarea`. The user is able to type a document in that `textarea`.

I used  WYSIWYG text editor to formate the text, so the `textarea` is changed to an `iframe` on runtime.

So I cannot the get the value from the `iframe`, but  I need the cursor line number and user high lighted text.

When user highlight the text the image has shown on end of the `textarea`.

I get it from text area [[textarea link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655007/how-to-add-image-on-end-of-textarea-in-user-selected-text-row-using-jquery)] but how can get the same from `iframe`

Comment: Could you provide your code: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fond42518/rxmzefje/

Comment: it working fine with textarea

Comment: Don't spam tag! BTW, you have to provide relevant code in question itself, and your jsfiddle isn't related to the iframe issue you are describing...

Comment: Every WYSIWYG editor that I know provides an API that should allow to retrieve those informations.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fz9ctps3/1/  - in the js fiddle click the link "Change Text Area" the image working line by line..

Comment: But using WYSIWYG editor not working please help

Comment: @Gael - check http://jsfiddle.net/fz9ctps3/11/

Answer (score 0):

The **linum** function counts the number of \n in the textarea:

```
function lineNum() {
    return doc.value.substr(0, doc.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
}
```

But in the WYSIWYG text editor, there is no new lines. If you switch, you can see all the html code in one line.

There is no simple way to know on which line the cursor is:

- You can set **useLineBreaks** option as true, but it changes only the way the editor interprets the Enter key: with <br> or <p>.
- a line can be truncate in case it is longer than the text area width without any information in the text.

I think you should rethink what you want, however, you can:

- get the [caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content),
- then add a markup
- get the [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of this markup